# The connectionstring property has not been initialized - AppSettings

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, connection-string, appsettings

Below is my connection string and I don't know where I am getting error.

```
<appSettings>

<!-- Default database to use... -->
<add key="Database_default" value="DB_Servername"/>

<!-- Datamart database connection to use -->
<add key="Database_datamart" value="MED_PROD"/>

<!--  Development Datamart Database Server -->
<add key="MED_PROD" value="Initial Catalog=REPORT_MED;Data Source=DB_Servername;UID=app_UID;PWD=******;"/>

<!--  Dev Server - Port Reference-->
<add key="va3fin01" value="Initial Catalog=acc;Data Source=DB_Servername;UID=med_UID;PWD=*******;"/>

<!-- MEDFIN_DEV -->
<add key="MED_DEV" value="Initial Catalog=MED_DEV;Data Source=DB_Servername;UID=med_UID;PWD=********;"/>

 </appSettings>
```

I cannot change any back end code. They asked me to change server. After changing servers I am getting "The connectionstring property has not been initialized" on a working app. Please let me know if there is anything I could take care of only on web.config

Please help!
Thanks

**Edited**

Below is the method using for getting the connection string.

```
private void GetConnectionString() 
    {
        string _settingname;

        // if its empty, update it with "default"
        if (this._database.Trim().Length == 0) this._database = "default";

        // get the setting...
        _settingname = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Database_" + this._database];
        if (_settingname == null) 
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to determine connection settings for specified database.");
        } 
        else
        {
            // retrieve the connection string from the specified database...
            this._ConnectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[_settingname];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try giving connection string in the code and check if it works or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, connection strings are inside ***connectionstring*** tag inside ***web.config***.

*For example,*

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="MED_PROD" connectionString="Initial Catalog=REPORT_MED;Data Source=DB_Servername;UID=app_UID;PWD=******;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
   <add name="va3fin01" connectionString="Initial Catalog=acc;Data Source=DB_Servername;UID=med_UID;PWD=*******;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
   <add name="MED_DEV" connectionString="Initial Catalog=MED_DEV;Data Source=DB_Servername;UID=med_UID;PWD=********;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: That's correct. But we also can use Appsettings and retrieve that connection using the method I have added. Please find and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: `<add key="Database_default" value="DB_Servername"/>` ***value*** should be either `MED_PROD`, `va3fin01` or `MED_DEV` instead of `DB_Servername`.

Comment: Yes! you are right! That change works. But I actually figured out when i walked through line by line again. Anyway thanks.